# how to avoid a loop or sapply to speed up a computation

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I have a very large dataset that can be described by the following `R` code:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(id = rep(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),2), h = rep(1:2,10), 
                   d = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10)), t = rep(c(sample(c(1,2,3), 5, replace = T),
                   sample(c(1,2,3), 5, replace = T)),2), q = runif(20), p = runif(20),
                   b = runif(20), w = rep(c(rep(.1,2), rep(.2,2)),5))
```

where `id`, is the subject id and `h` and `d` are hours and days. Each `id` has multiple `t`. For each type of `t` (which can be 1, 2, or 3), indexed by `t_i`, in each `h` and `d`, I need to compute the summation over the `t = t_i` of `q_i * pnorm((p_i - b_i)/ w_i)`. The output should ideally be an additional column to the `data.frame` `data`.

What is the fastest way to compute this? My dataset is very large, and I'm afraid that a `for loop` or `sapply` will take forever. I was thinking of using the `aggregate` function but I am not sure it works with expressions other than `mean` or `sum`.

---- FIXED A TYPO IN THE DGP ----

Example: Given the data (`set.seed(1)`) The last column give the output while `Sum` gives the multiplication `q_i * pnorm((p_i - b_i)/ w_i)` by row. Rows 1 and 4 have same conditioning variables and thus have the same value in the `result` column because this would be equal to `q_1 * pnorm((p_1 - b_1)/ w_1) +`q_5 * pnorm((p_5 - b_5)/ w_5)``. I'M SORRY IF I WAS NOT CLEAR.

```
     id h d t          q         p          b   w          Sum       result
1.1   1 1 1 1 0.20597457 0.4820801 0.47761962 0.1 1.066513e-01 8.764928e-01
2.2   1 2 1 2 0.17655675 0.5995658 0.86120948 0.1 7.843788e-04 7.843788e-04
2.3   1 1 1 2 0.68702285 0.4935413 0.43809711 0.2 4.185307e-01 4.185307e-01
3.4   1 2 1 3 0.38410372 0.1862176 0.24479728 0.2 1.478031e-01 1.478031e-01
1.5   1 1 1 1 0.76984142 0.8273733 0.07067905 0.1 7.698414e-01 8.764928e-01
3.6   2 2 1 3 0.49769924 0.6684667 0.09946616 0.1 4.976992e-01 4.976992e-01
3.7   2 1 1 3 0.71761851 0.7942399 0.31627171 0.2 7.115705e-01 7.115705e-01
2.8   2 2 1 2 0.99190609 0.1079436 0.51863426 0.2 1.985233e-02 1.985233e-02
2.9   2 1 1 2 0.38003518 0.7237109 0.66200508 0.1 2.779585e-01 2.779585e-01
1.10  2 2 1 1 0.77744522 0.4112744 0.40683019 0.1 4.025021e-01 4.025021e-01
1.11  1 1 2 1 0.93470523 0.8209463 0.91287592 0.2 3.018017e-01 3.745763e-01
2.12  1 2 2 2 0.21214252 0.6470602 0.29360337 0.2 2.039559e-01 2.039559e-01
2.13  1 1 2 2 0.65167377 0.7829328 0.45906573 0.1 6.512825e-01 6.512825e-01
3.14  1 2 2 3 0.12555510 0.5530363 0.33239467 0.1 1.238378e-01 1.238378e-01
1.15  1 1 2 1 0.26722067 0.5297196 0.65087047 0.2 7.277459e-02 3.745763e-01
3.16  2 2 2 3 0.38611409 0.7893562 0.25801678 0.2 3.845907e-01 3.845907e-01
3.17  2 1 2 3 0.01339033 0.0233312 0.47854525 0.1 3.555325e-08 3.555325e-08
2.18  2 2 2 2 0.38238796 0.4772301 0.76631067 0.1 7.346728e-04 7.346728e-04
2.19  2 1 2 2 0.86969085 0.7323137 0.08424691 0.2 8.691717e-01 8.691717e-01
1.20  2 2 2 1 0.34034900 0.6927316 0.87532133 0.2 6.147884e-02 6.147884e-02
```

Comment: `aggregate` works with any function. You can define your own named function or even use an anonymous one.

Comment: Thank you! but how to write the expression? I have to aggregate over `t_i`, `q_i`, `p_i`, `b_i` and `w_i`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `group_by(t, id, h, d)` then calculate the `Sum` for each row then finally calculate the total sum `result` for rows that have the same `t, id, h, d`

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
options(scipen = 999)

dat <- data.frame(id = rep(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),2), h = rep(1:2,5), 
                   d = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10)), 
                   t = rep(c(sample(c(1,2,3), 5, replace = T),
                   sample(c(1,2,3), 5, replace = T)),2), q = runif(20), p = runif(20),
                   b = runif(20), w = rep(c(rep(.1,2), rep(.2,2)),5))
dat

#>    id h d t          q         p          b   w
#> 1   1 1 1 1 0.20597457 0.4820801 0.47761962 0.1
#> 2   1 2 1 2 0.17655675 0.5995658 0.86120948 0.1
#> 3   1 1 1 2 0.68702285 0.4935413 0.43809711 0.2
#> 4   1 2 1 3 0.38410372 0.1862176 0.24479728 0.2
#> 5   1 1 1 1 0.76984142 0.8273733 0.07067905 0.1
#> 6   2 2 1 3 0.49769924 0.6684667 0.09946616 0.1
#> 7   2 1 1 3 0.71761851 0.7942399 0.31627171 0.2
#> 8   2 2 1 2 0.99190609 0.1079436 0.51863426 0.2
#> 9   2 1 1 2 0.38003518 0.7237109 0.66200508 0.1
#> 10  2 2 1 1 0.77744522 0.4112744 0.40683019 0.1
#> 11  1 1 2 1 0.93470523 0.8209463 0.91287592 0.2
#> 12  1 2 2 2 0.21214252 0.6470602 0.29360337 0.2
#> 13  1 1 2 2 0.65167377 0.7829328 0.45906573 0.1
#> 14  1 2 2 3 0.12555510 0.5530363 0.33239467 0.1
#> 15  1 1 2 1 0.26722067 0.5297196 0.65087047 0.2
#> 16  2 2 2 3 0.38611409 0.7893562 0.25801678 0.2
#> 17  2 1 2 3 0.01339033 0.0233312 0.47854525 0.1
#> 18  2 2 2 2 0.38238796 0.4772301 0.76631067 0.1
#> 19  2 1 2 2 0.86969085 0.7323137 0.08424691 0.2
#> 20  2 2 2 1 0.34034900 0.6927316 0.87532133 0.2

dat %>% 
  group_by(t, id, h, d) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = q * pnorm((p - b)/w)) %>% 
  mutate(result = sum(Sum))

#> # A tibble: 20 x 10
#> # Groups:   t, id, h, d [18]
#>       id     h     d     t      q      p      b     w          Sum  result
#>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1    1.     1    1.    1. 0.206  0.482  0.478  0.100 0.107        8.76e-1
#>  2    1.     2    1.    2. 0.177  0.600  0.861  0.100 0.000784     7.84e-4
#>  3    1.     1    1.    2. 0.687  0.494  0.438  0.200 0.419        4.19e-1
#>  4    1.     2    1.    3. 0.384  0.186  0.245  0.200 0.148        1.48e-1
#>  5    1.     1    1.    1. 0.770  0.827  0.0707 0.100 0.770        8.76e-1
#>  6    2.     2    1.    3. 0.498  0.668  0.0995 0.100 0.498        4.98e-1
#>  7    2.     1    1.    3. 0.718  0.794  0.316  0.200 0.712        7.12e-1
#>  8    2.     2    1.    2. 0.992  0.108  0.519  0.200 0.0199       1.99e-2
#>  9    2.     1    1.    2. 0.380  0.724  0.662  0.100 0.278        2.78e-1
#> 10    2.     2    1.    1. 0.777  0.411  0.407  0.100 0.403        4.03e-1
#> 11    1.     1    2.    1. 0.935  0.821  0.913  0.200 0.302        3.75e-1
#> 12    1.     2    2.    2. 0.212  0.647  0.294  0.200 0.204        2.04e-1
#> 13    1.     1    2.    2. 0.652  0.783  0.459  0.100 0.651        6.51e-1
#> 14    1.     2    2.    3. 0.126  0.553  0.332  0.100 0.124        1.24e-1
#> 15    1.     1    2.    1. 0.267  0.530  0.651  0.200 0.0728       3.75e-1
#> 16    2.     2    2.    3. 0.386  0.789  0.258  0.200 0.385        3.85e-1
#> 17    2.     1    2.    3. 0.0134 0.0233 0.479  0.100 0.0000000356 3.56e-8
#> 18    2.     2    2.    2. 0.382  0.477  0.766  0.100 0.000735     7.35e-4
#> 19    2.     1    2.    2. 0.870  0.732  0.0842 0.200 0.869        8.69e-1
#> 20    2.     2    2.    1. 0.340  0.693  0.875  0.200 0.0615       6.15e-2
```

Created on 2018-03-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I don't know the `tidyverse` package. It sees pretty cool. However, it gives me this error: `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 2 must be length 6, not 2`. Did it work for you?

Comment: I had a typo in the code. The hour `h` should actually be `h = rep(1:2,5)` otherwise you never sum across equal `t_i`s in the same `h`. Also, I think the result is not correct. For the first line it should be: `0.95683335 + pnorm((0.96302423- 0.04583117)/ 0.1) = 1.956833`. If there were another row with with same `h`, `d` `id` and `t` it should have summed  this value with the corresponding `q * pnorm((p - b)/w))` for this other row. But this looks very quick! Can we fix it?

Comment: Should it b something like 
`dat %>% 
  mutate_if(grepl(c('t','id','h','d'), names(dat)), funs(result = sum(q * pnorm((p - b)/w))))` ? That is, I should subset `dat` by `t`, `id`,`h`, `d`, and sum the function over the observations that fulfill this criteria. but it gives me a `Warning` and the wrong result.

Comment: Try something like this: `data %>% mutate(myfun=q * pnorm((p - b)/ w) )%>%group_by(id, t, h, d) %>% summarise(sum(myfun))`

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e. Does it work for you? The output it produces is still a vector of different numbers, while same occurrences of `t`,`id`, `h` and `d` should have the same values.

Comment: @Andrew: I think I misunderstood you. Can you post your expected output with your manual calculation? That would be helpful

Comment: example added. :)

Comment: Great, thank you! How does this function deal with `NA`? Is there a way to omit them from the sum? just adding `sum(Sum, na.rm = T)` will work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R base approach using `ave`. I am not sure if this solves your problem, but here's an attempt for you to figure out how to write the expression:

```
data$Aggregated.Sum <- ave(data[, c("q", "p", "b", "w")], 
                            data[,c("id", "h", "d", "t")], 
                            FUN=function(x){
                              sum(x$q * pnorm((x$p - x$b)/ x$w))
                            })[, 1]
```

Giving the following output:

```
   id h d t          q         p          b   w   Aggregated.Sum
1   1 1 1 1 0.20597457 0.4820801 0.47761962 0.1 0.87649276750008
2   1 2 1 2 0.17655675 0.5995658 0.86120948 0.1 0.00078437884830
3   1 1 1 2 0.68702285 0.4935413 0.43809711 0.2 0.41853074006211
4   1 2 1 3 0.38410372 0.1862176 0.24479728 0.2 0.14780307785185
5   1 1 1 1 0.76984142 0.8273733 0.07067905 0.1 0.87649276750008
6   2 2 1 3 0.49769924 0.6684667 0.09946616 0.1 0.49769923892396
7   2 1 1 3 0.71761851 0.7942399 0.31627171 0.2 0.71157053468214
8   2 2 1 2 0.99190609 0.1079436 0.51863426 0.2 0.01985232872822
9   2 1 1 2 0.38003518 0.7237109 0.66200508 0.1 0.27795848822967
10  2 2 1 1 0.77744522 0.4112744 0.40683019 0.1 0.40250214883360
11  1 1 2 1 0.93470523 0.8209463 0.91287592 0.2 0.37457632092225
12  1 2 2 2 0.21214252 0.6470602 0.29360337 0.2 0.20395587133630
13  1 1 2 2 0.65167377 0.7829328 0.45906573 0.1 0.65128247418102
14  1 2 2 3 0.12555510 0.5530363 0.33239467 0.1 0.12383782495223
15  1 1 2 1 0.26722067 0.5297196 0.65087047 0.2 0.37457632092225
16  2 2 2 3 0.38611409 0.7893562 0.25801678 0.2 0.38459067414776
17  2 1 2 3 0.01339033 0.0233312 0.47854525 0.1 0.00000003555325
18  2 2 2 2 0.38238796 0.4772301 0.76631067 0.1 0.00073467275547
19  2 1 2 2 0.86969085 0.7323137 0.08424691 0.2 0.86917168501551
20  2 2 2 1 0.34034900 0.6927316 0.87532133 0.2 0.06147884477362
```

Comment: this seems promising, I've never used the `split` function. Thank you. Now I need to find a way to condition the split. Does `unlist` always return the `sum_i` data in the same order as it was before the splitting?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't : `sum_i <- lapply(split(data[, -4], data[,4]), function(x){
  x$q
})
data$result <- unlist(sum_i)`

Comment: @Andrew you're right, now the order is correct, see edit

Comment: I'm not getting the right result because same combinations of `id`, `h`, `d` and `t` should give the same value on the `sum` column in `data2`, but it doesn't. All values in `data2` are different. How can we fix this? Thank you!

Comment: consider that you're running a random generation of numbers, set the seed and make sure your example and your output is reproducible

Comment: I set `set.seed(1)`. From the output, the last column from these two observations should be the same because I should be summing over the same quantities as these two rows have the same `id`,`h`,`d` and `t`:

`1.1   1 1 1 1 0.20597457 0.4820801 0.47761962 0.1 1.066513e-01`         

`1.5   1 1 1 1 0.76984142 0.8273733 0.07067905 0.1 7.698414e-01`

The code should give in the last column the`sum(x$q * pnorm((x$p - x$b)/ x$w))` where `x` should be a matrix with 2 rows only (as only this row as `id`,`h`,`d` and `t` equal to 1).

Comment: Your code computes `x$q * pnorm((x$p - x$b)/ x$w)` for each row of the `data.frame`. Is there a way to include the summation across rows with the same entries for `id`, `h`, `d`, `t` and print it in an adjacent column? That'd give the result.

Comment: adding these two lines it works:
`data3 <- aggregate(Sum ~ id + h + d + t, data = data2, sum)` 

`data2$result <- data3[match(paste(data2$id, data2$h, data2$d, data2$t), paste(data3$id, data3$h, data3$d, data3$t) ), "Sum"]`
But is there a way to make it works with the `lapply` function? I think it would be faster that way.

Comment: @Andrew Now that I am clear about what you are after, I re-write my answer using `ave` and it gives the result you´re looking for. Now, we can clean all these comments since they have nothing to do with the current answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you expected

```
data <- split(data, data$id)
data <- lapply(data, function(i) {split(i,i$t)})
data <- unlist(data,recursive=FALSE)

data1 <- lapply(data, function(j)
  {
  res <- j[,c("q","p","b","w")]
  j$result <- apply(res,1,function(i) i["q"] *pnorm( (i["p"] - i["b"]))/ i["w"] )
  j
  })

data1 <- do.call(rbind, data1)
```